# Why am I getting a serialization error?

Tags: c#, exception, .net-3.5, serialization, c#-3.0

I have the following code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string xml = @"<ArrayOfUserSetting>
                            <UserSetting>
                                <Value>Proposals</Value>
                                <Name>LastGroup</Name>
                            </UserSetting>
                            <UserSetting>
                                <Value>Visible</Value>
                                <Name>WidgetsVisibility</Name>
                            </UserSetting>
                        </ArrayOfUserSetting>";

        List<UserSetting> settings = 
                 GetObjFromXmlDocument<List<UserSetting>>(xml);
    }

    public static T GetObjFromXmlDocument<T>(string xml)
    {
        T customType;

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDocument.LoadXml(xml);
        using (XmlNodeReader xmlNodeReader = new XmlNodeReader(xmlDocument))
        {
            customType = (T)serializer.Deserialize(xmlNodeReader);
        }

        return customType;
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class UserSetting
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The code works fine and the call to GetObjFromXmlDocument yields a List collection.  However, I always get a first chance exception of type `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` in mscorlib.dll, when `XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));` is executed.

So I went into Debug/Exception and turned on Managed Debugging Assistants.  I got the following on that line:

> The assembly with display name 'mscorlib.XmlSerializers' failed to load in the 'LoadFrom' binding context of the AppDomain with ID 1. The cause of the failure was: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'mscorlib.XmlSerializers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   File name: 'mscorlib.XmlSerializers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

Can someone explain why this is happening?  Is there something I could do to the `UserSetting` class to make the problem disappear?  The application is quite performance sensitive and I'd rather not have the exception.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Microsoft says](http://web.archive.org/web/20101023030415/http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/93647/xml-serializer-throws-file-not-found-exceptions):

> XmlSerializer attempts to load
>   pre-generated serializers to avoid
>   compilation of the serialization code
>   on the fly. There is no easy way to
>   check for "will assembly be found by
>   the Assembly.Load() call", it would be
>   duplicating Fusion path search and
>   loader logic in XmlSerializer.

It looks like a FileNotFound exception is thrown and handled in the XmlSerializer when the "pre-generated serializer" cannot be found, which will then cause the serialization code to be generated.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful! More to the issue, if you see this while debugging, just hit F5 and your program will keep going (it won't crash...at least not b/c of this).

Answer (score 2):

**Update 04/2022:** As @Pierre Fournier notes in his comment below, this merely hides the error. You should only do this as a last resort.

For the select few Visual Studio projects I have where this is an annoyance, I prefer to disable break on exception for just the **BindingFailure** and the **System.IO.FileNotFoundException**.

In Visual Studio: Ctl-D, Ctl-E for the Exceptions dialog:

1. Uncheck BindingFailure under **Managed Debugging Assistants**
2. Uncheck System.IO.FileNotFoundException  under **Common Language Runtime Exceptions**.

Ahhh that’s better :-)

Comment: How is this better?  Instead of finding a fix to the problem, you're just covering your eyes to not see it.  Nothing fixed.  In fact, it's now worst because you'll miss other FileNotFound exceptions that might be important.

Comment: Fair point @PierreFournier. I've updated the answer. Thanks for the critique. I use this ONLY in the rare case this issue surfaces in third-party libraries or other code I can't - or am not at liberty to - fix.